# Match strings of files in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have 3 files at a directory $FILES_DIR

```
1) File_Apple.txt
2) File_Samsung.txt
3) File_Huwaei.txt

Header rows of File_Apple.txt

    AAA1,BBB2,CCC3

Header rows of File_Samsung.txt

    DDD1,EEE2

Header rows of File_Huwaei.txt

    FFF1,GGG2,HHH3,III4
```

There's another file called head_config which contains the header line of the above 3 files.

head_config.txt

```
AAA1,BBB2,CCC3
DDD1,EEE2
FFF1,GGG2,HHH3,III4
```

Basically i have to match if the headers of the file are correct as per the head_config.txt file

I am able to do so by some cumbersome process:
copying header rows of each file individually and appending to a new file. Then comparing new file created with head.config.txt

```
head -1 File_Apple.txt >> new_file.txt
head -1 File_Samsung.txt >> new_file.txt
head -1  File_Huwaei.txt >> new_file.txt
```

Then cmp new_file.txt to head_config.txt

How can i do it more efficiently?

Comment: That isn't really "cumbersome". The only suggestion I'd have is a for loop of files in case you end up with 30 instead of 3 - that would be cumbersome ;-)

Comment: what is the desired output? 'yes' or 'no' that you have a 100% match across all files? a list of files that have matching headers? a list of files that don't have a matching header? can multiple files have the same header and if so does the header show up once or multiple times in `head_config.txt`?

Comment: @John3136 : thanks! I agree loop is required as files number may increase.

Comment: @markp: Output can be anything. Yes or No. Good or Bad. Multiple files can have some same headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one command that does it all, printing `Good` for each file that matches and `Bad` for the ones that don't:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{hdr[NR]=$0;next} {print FILENAME, (hdr[++i]==$0?"Good":"Bad"); nextfile}' head_config.txt File_Apple.txt File_Samsung.txt File_Huwaei.txt 
File_Apple.txt Good
File_Samsung.txt Good
File_Huwaei.txt Good
```

The output is quite flexible and can be changed to meet special needs you may have.

#### How it works

- `NR==NR{hdr[NR]=$0;next}`

  For the first file, `head_config.txt`, this reads each line into the array `dhr`.
- `print FILENAME, (hdr[++i]==$0?"Good":"Bad"); nextfile`

  For each of the remaining files, this checks to see if its first line matches the corresponding element of `hdr`: `hdr[++i]==$0`.  If it does the file name and `Good` is printed.  Otherwise, the file name and `Bad` is printed.

Comment: Thanks John! This is really helpful. AWK is indeed very useful.

Answer (score 3):

First, ensure that the lines in your header file are sorted alphabetically by **filename**. So head_config.txt becomes:

```
AAA1,BBB2,CCC3
FFF1,GGG2,HHH3,III4
DDD1,EEE2AAA1,BBB2,CCC3
```

Then execute this command:

```
diff head_config.txt <(head -q -n1 File_*)
```

If the files match, there will be no output, and `$?` will be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Chek this one with AWK

```
for file in ./File_*
do
  for line in `cat head_config.txt`
  do
    awk -v var="$line" '$0 ~ var && NR==1 {print FILENAME "PASSED TEST"}' $file
  done
done
```